# Java Insertion Sort not sorting

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Movies2[] movies = new Movies2[10];

    movies[0] = new Movies2("The Muppets Take Manhattan", 2001, "Columbia Tristar");
    movies[1] = new Movies2("Mulan Special Edition", 2004, "Disney");
    movies[2] = new Movies2("Shrek 2", 2004, "Dreamworks");
    movies[3] = new Movies2("The Incredibles", 2004, "Pixar");
    movies[4] = new Movies2("Nanny McPhee", 2006, "Universal");
    movies[5] = new Movies2("The Curse of the Were-Rabbit", 2006, "Aardman");
    movies[6] = new Movies2("Ice Age", 2002, "20th Century Fox");
    movies[7] = new Movies2("Lilo & Stitch", 2002, "Disney");
    movies[8] = new Movies2("Robots", 2005, "20th Century Fox");
    movies[9] = new Movies2("Monsters Inc.", 2001, "Pixar");

    printMovies(movies);
    sortTitle(movies, 1);
    printMovies(movies);
    //sortYear(movies, 2);
    //printMovies(movies);
    //sortStudio(movies, 1);
    //printMovies(movies);
}

public static void printMovies(Movies2[] list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        System.out.println(list[i]);
}

public static Movies2[] sortTitle(Movies2[] source, int direction)
{
   Movies2[] dest = new Movies2[ source.length ];
   if(direction == 1)
   {
   System.out.println("Sort by Title - ascending");
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < source.length ; i++ )
    {
       Movies2 next = source[i];
       int insertindex = 0;
       int k = i;
       while ( k > 0 && insertindex == 0 )
       {
          if ( next.getTitle().compareTo(dest[k-1].getTitle()) > 0 )
          {
              insertindex = k;
          }
          else
          {
             dest[ k ] = dest[ k - 1 ];
          }
           k--;
       }
       dest[ insertindex ] = next;
    } 
}
else if( direction == 2)
{
    System.out.println("Sort by Title - descending");
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < source.length ; i++ )
    {
       Movies2 next = source[ i ];
       int insertindex = 0;
       int k = i;
       while ( k > 0 && insertindex == 0 )
       {
          if ( next.getTitle().compareTo(dest[k-1].getTitle()) < 0 )
          {
              insertindex = k;
          }
          else
          {
             dest[ k ] = dest[ k + 1 ];
          }
           k--;
       }
       dest[ insertindex ] = next;
    } 

}
else 
{
    dest = source;
}
   return dest;
```

}
I have this code with the array of movies.  In the movies class there are getter methods for all the parameters.  When I try to run this code with the number being 2, the descending choice, it gives me a null error.  When I try it with 1 for ascending, it doesn't sort it.

Comment: Post the error please; it will give us specific information as to what exactly is causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to implement Comparable interface with you Movie class and use the Collections.sort method?

Comment: What about Arrays.sort ?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at testMovie2.sortTitle(testMovie2.java:76)
 at testMovie2.main(testMovie2.java:26)  is the error that I get

Comment: Line 76 of testMovie2.java?

Comment: if ( next.getTitle().compareTo(dest[k-1].getTitle()) < 0 )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
if (next.getTitle().compareTo(dest[k - 1].getTitle()) > 0) {
```

May be `next.getTitle()` is `null`. Title is not set properly.

---

**Try this simple method to sort your array:**

```
public static void sort(Movies2[] numbers, boolean ascending) {

    Movies2 tempVar = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < numbers.length - i; j++) {
            int diff = numbers[j - 1].getTitle().compareTo(numbers[j].getTitle());
            if ((ascending && diff > 0) || (!ascending && diff < 0)) {
                tempVar = numbers[j - 1];
                numbers[j - 1] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = tempVar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the `Movies2` constructor & `getTitle()` method.

Comment: private String title, studio;
    private int year;
    
    Movies2(String t, int y, String s)
    {
        title = t;
        year = y;
        studio = s;
    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    } is what I have in the Movies2 class, not sure where the problem could be occurring

Comment: Please share `Movies2` file if you are unable to find it out.

Comment: if ( next.getTitle().compareTo(dest[k-1].getTitle()) < 0 )

Comment: Its the same line that I have mentioned in my post.

Comment: Right, but you said that the issue should then be in either the constructor or the getTitle() method but they both seem correct.

Comment: Please share Movies2 file if you are unable to find it out.

Comment: The whole class is public class Movies2
{
    private String title, studio;
    private int year;
    
    Movies2(String t, int y, String s)
    {
        title = t;
        year = y;
        studio = s;
    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
    public String getStudio()
    {
        return studio;
    }
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return title + ", " + year + ", " + studio;
    }
}

Comment: `dest[k - 1]` is null for k=3 at the above line.

Comment: Can you try `Comparable` interface to make it simple.

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look. Its very easy and simple to understand.